# tikzmarknode not working in Overleaf

Tags: tikzmark

I have started going through all of the bookmarked answers on StackExchange that I want to use for examples. I have had success with most of the answers being able to compile within Overleaf. However, I tried importing the code from [How do I get a tilted equal sign for an equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461487/how-do-i-get-a-tilted-equal-sign-for-an-equation) and its answer into Overleaf. Specifically I tried to use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\[\lim_{x\to0}\tikzmarknode{ex}{\mathrm{e}^x}\left(2+4x\right)~=~2\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\path[red] ([xshift=1pt,yshift=1pt]ex.north east) -- ++(45:{width("=")*1pt-1pt})
node[midway,sloped]{$=$} node[above right=-2pt]{$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I compile in Overleaf I receive the following two errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \[\lim_{x\to0}\tikzmarknode{ex}{\mathrm{e}^x}\left(2+4x\right)~=~2\]
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! Package pgf Error: No shape named ex is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.8 ...red] ([xshift=1pt,yshift=1pt]ex.north east)
                                              -- ++(45:{width("=")*1pt-...
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.
```

I believe that the second error (No shaped named ex is found) is due to the first error not creating the node.

Comment: Unfortunately I am having issues getting MikTeX to work on my school laptop to test out the same code using current libraries.

Comment: The version of `tikzmark` in Overleaf doesn't have `\tikzmarknode`. I even used this macro as a test to find out the version of `tikzmark` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474942/134574). You can copy the code of `tikzmark` from CTAN and upload it to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a test missing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\[\lim_{x\to0}\tikzmarknode{ex}{\mathrm{e}^x}\left(2+4x\right)~=~2\]
\iftikzmark{ex}{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\path[red] ([xshift=1pt,yshift=1pt]ex.north east) -- ++(45:{width("=")*1pt-1pt})
node[midway,sloped]{$=$} node[above right=-2pt]{$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just copied it into overleaf and I am still receiving the first error.

Comment: then the overleaf version is too old, on texlive 2019 it works with my change.

Comment: Once I get home I will test with textlive and accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Do you only get the error on the first compilation?  (Or after deleting the aux file?)  If so, this is a known bug which is fixed on github and just waiting for the lazy author to upload it to ctan.

Comment: @LoopSpace yes, that's my error.

Comment: Thought so.  Uploading the latest version is on my todo list ...

Answer (score 0):

Add [these two files](http://www.tug.org/texlive//devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikzmark/) into your overleaf project, and it will work. I had the same problem and that worked it out.

Comment: Thanks Pedro. After getting it to work on my local install I added those files to Overleaf and was successful. I am trying to make templates and examples for my students to use when typing up their homework answers, I guess that I will have to put those files in our class Google Drive so that they can include them when using this technique.